# c# Deserialize json into List

Tags: c#, json, list, object, serialization

I have this code that retrieves Json string from API link. The Json is deserialized and returned to a textbox. This works perfectly as long as there is only 1 Json value, being returned more than 1 value it crashes with this error:

> Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'GW2_tradingPost.RootObject' because the type
>   requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize
>   correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g.
>   {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a
>   type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList)
>   like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array.
>   JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON array.

Doing my research this happens because there is nowhere to deposit the Json since its not an List.

I've have tried this code and various similar ones.

```
List<RootObject> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(jsonReader.ToString());
return list;
```

This will return with error:

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'GW2_tradingPost.RootObject'  e:\mega\gw2_tradingpost\gw2_tradingpost\api_request.cs  34

Which i dont fully understand what it means.

Here is my full code.

api_Request.cs

```
public class api_Request
    {
        public RootObject GetApi(string url)
        {

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            try
            {
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader);
                var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                return serializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(jsonReader);
            }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                WebResponse errorResponse = ex.Response;
                using (Stream responseStream = errorResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
                    String errorText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    // log errorText
                }
                throw;
            }
        }

    }


    public class Buy
    {
        public int listings { get; set; }
        public int unit_price { get; set; }
        public int quantity { get; set; }
    }

    public class Sell
    {
        public int listings { get; set; }
        public int unit_price { get; set; }
        public int quantity { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public List<Buy> buys { get; set; }
        public List<Sell> sells { get; set; }
    }
```

Form1.cs

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RootObject RootObject = new RootObject();
            api_Request api_Request = new api_Request();
            richTextBox1.Text = api_Request.GetApi("https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/commerce/listings").id.ToString();
        }
```

In this json is a single ID, so this works fine. https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/commerce/listings/19684

But when retrieving multiple ID's like here, it breaks.
https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/commerce/listings

Comment: can we see an example of the json you are trying to parse? as you are trying to deserialize in to a list of root objects, but at the root object level, it is trying to parse a list, so my thoughts are that you have nested lists

Comment: @DavidWatts I have edited the post, at the bottom there are 2 Api links that will show you what the Json looks like.

Comment: They return completely different things. The multiple ID's link returns an array of ints, which I'm gussing are the ID's of single listings. It looks like you would have to query for all the listings, then run another one per listing to get the actual object. Try it, and if it works, I'll throw an answer up, otherwise, I'll continue to try and help

Comment: How do i query for all listings? Isnt a query database related?

Comment: When you make the API call to retrieve multiple ID's, a query will be ran on their end. I am suggesting that you make the call for multiple ID's and deserilze it to an int[], then once you have done that, use a `foreach` loop to make the request for each ID individually. That's gonna be a hell of a lot of web requests, but if you are paging them in the display, you only need to make the request for as many as you display

Comment: Is this question dead now. Both of the answers provide the solution to this issue. It would be great if you could accept one of them so that people who have similar issues can quickly see that there is a solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution to get listing of all id's it will a real amount of time though to go through all of them

```
  List<RootObject> rootobject = new List<RootObject>();
    using (var webclient = new WebClient())
    {
        var Ids = webclient.DownloadString(" https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/commerce/listings");
        foreach (var id in Ids.Substring(1, s.Length-2).Split(','))
        {
            string url = string.Format("{0}/{1}","https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/commerce/listings",id);
            var res = webclient.DownloadString(url);
            var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(res);
            rootobject.Add(jsonObject);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The link that you provided for multiple ID's return an Array of Integers. I would suggest parsing this as such:

```
var ids = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int[]>(jsonReader.ToString())
```

As you have said, your code works for a single item, so you can use your existing code for each individual request which instead of hitting  `https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/commerce/listings`, will be hitting `https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/commerce/listings/{id}` which you can use `string.Format()` to add where it is needed.

Seriously consider how many of the id's returned in the `int[]` you actually want to fetch the root object for though, as from what I can see that it returns, you will be making a hell of a lot of requests.